# Modeshape querying mixinTypes

Tags: jcr, modeshape, jcr-sql2

I'm using Modeshape and modeshape-connector-jdbc-metadata. I want to get all nodes representing tables in the storage. That nodes have `[mj:catalog]` mixin type.

I'm querying storage using next code:

```
    public List getDatabases() throws RepositoryException {
        // Obtain the query manager for the session ...
        QueryManager queryManager = dbSession.getWorkspace().getQueryManager();

        // Create a query object ...
        Query query = queryManager.createQuery("SELECT * FROM [mj:table]"
                , Query.JCR_SQL2);
        // Execute the query and get the results ...
        QueryResult result = query.execute();

        // Iterate over the nodes in the results ...
        NodeIterator nodeIter = result.getNodes();

        List stringResult = new ArrayList();
        while (nodeIter.hasNext()) {
            stringResult.add(nodeIter.nextNode().getName());
        }

        return stringResult;
    }
```

But it always returns empty list.

I also tried to query using next queries:

```
SELECT unst.*, tbl.* FROM [nt:unstructured] AS unst 
    JOIN [mj:table] AS tbl ON ISSAMENODE(unst,tbl)
```

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:unstructured] WHERE [jcr:mixinTypes] = [mj:table]
```

But result remains the same. 
What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue that the database metadata nodes are not indexed automatically. A simple workaround is to cast the JCR Session's `getWorkspace()` instance to `org.modeshape.jcr.api.Workspace` (the public API for ModeShape's workspace) and call the `reindex(String path)` method and passing in the path to the database catalog node (or an ancestor if desired).